# how to create Windows application installation/setup select component window?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, installation, setup-project

I am creating a windows application setup project using Visual studio 2008 setup project. This setup will have following steps:

1. Splash screen
2. Select Installation folder/directory
3. Database configuration
4. **Select Components**

I am having trouble finding a way to create such installation window in setup. could you please help me to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's routine for creating install/setup files is fairly weak compared to what you can find out there. Personally, I use a program called [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It's an extremely powerful scripting program that allows you to completely customize the installation process. You may have to spend a little bit of time learning the basics of the scripting language it uses but will be well worth whatever time you may spend understanding the language to use the setup utility to create complete installation files for your current and future programs.

Comment: thanks Aandy. I will check Inno Setup and will discuss with you. Is it possible to create such a setup using Microsoft Dot net framework?